Azure Load balancer sending requests to different servers
I have 2 Azure VM's load balanced by a Azure Load Balancer. Timeout on the balancer is set to 60 minutes. The web app is deployed to both vm's and works fine. However, after a period of inactivity the balancer sends the requests to a different server than before and fails.
Session Persistence is set to "Client IP and protocol", Idle Timeout = 60, and Enable TCP Reset is checked. What am I missing here?

#1 Is your inactivity period higher than your limit (60 minutes)?  #2 What do you mean by "fails" ? Share some azure logs or your app logs. Maybe is an error in your application session handler or configuration

@JRichardsz I assume 'fails' means the web app requires session affinity to function properly- by switching servers, the app is missing in-memory data it needs. But I agree, we don't have enough information here to help. How long is the "period of inactivity"? Should we assume client IP+protocol is the same before/after the client switches servers?
